# How to get many to many value in Django template

Tags: django, templates, many-to-many

I have 2 app: `authors_app` and `books_app`

`authors_app.models`:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

`books_app.models`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='authors')
```

Authors_app Views.py

```
class AuthorBio(DetailView):
    model = Author
    template_name = 'author-bio.html'
```

**Problem**

I need to get all the book published by the author.
In my template I try:

```
{% for book in author.books.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work

**Question**

How can I get all the books by the author

Answer (score 0):

First change

```
author = models.ManyToManyField(...)
```

to

```
authors = models.ManyToManyField('authors_app.author', related_name="books")
```

now you can access books using `related_name`: `author.books.all()`

Code Example:

```
>>> from authors_app.models import Author
>>> Author.objects.create(name="J.K. Rowling")
<Author: J.K. Rowling>
>>> from books_app.models import Book
>>> jk = Author.objects.first()
>>> jk
<Author: J.K. Rowling>
>>> Book.objects.create(name="Harry Potter: Chamber of secrets")
<Book: Harry Potter: Chamber of secrets>
>>> hp = Book.objects.first()
>>> hp.authors.set([jk])
>>> jk.books.all()
<QuerySet [<Book: Harry Potter: Chamber of secrets>]>
>>>
```

> Pay attention to your queryset performance.

Comment: Thank you
But how can I get the list of books with related name? 
like: {% for book in author.book_set.all %} for {% for book in author.books.all %}
I think that would be a better solution

Comment: @TiBrains Yes, i'll update the answer